# JButton changes size when pressing toggleButton

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, resize, calculator

I have a problem with my GUI in that when I press a toggle button belonging to a certain panel, the panels buttons changes size and labels change positions. I've attached some screenshots to show the error in action. I believe its because the buttons are sharing the same panel but I'm unsure whether its fixable so that the buttons size remains static, as do the labels positions.

My code is below (sorry that its quite messy!. I have alot of nested BorderLayout JPanels and this could be where the problem is, but for me it was the easiest way to get the correct layout.

```
package v2;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener; 
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;

public class BmrCalcv2 extends JFrame {

    // Frames and main panels
    static JFrame mainFrame;
    static JPanel mainPanel;
    static JPanel combinedGAHWpanel; // combines genderPanel, agePanel, heightPanel, weightPanel - this
                                     // is a BorderLayout, whereas
                                     // gender/agePanel are FlowLayouts.
    static JPanel weightHeightPanel; // Combines weight and height panel into out flowlayout panel, which is then combined into the above borderlayout panel

    // Image components
    static JPanel imgPanel;
    private JLabel imgLabel;

    // Menu-bar components
    static JMenuBar menuBar;
    static JMenu saveMenu, optionMenu, helpMenu;

    // Age components
    static JPanel agePanel;
    private JLabel ageLabel;
    private JLabel yearsLabel;
    private JTextField ageTextField;

    // Gender components
    static JPanel genderPanel;
    private JLabel genderLabel;
    private JRadioButton genderMale;
    private JRadioButton genderFemale;


    // Height components
    static JPanel heightPanel;
    private JLabel heightLabel;
    private JTextField heightCMField;
    private JLabel heightFTLabel;
    private JLabel heightINCHLabel;
    private JTextField heightFTField;
    private JTextField heightINCHField;
    private JToggleButton cmButton;
    private JToggleButton feetButton;


    // Weight components
    static JPanel weightPanel;
    private JLabel weightLabel;
    private JTextField weightField;
    private JToggleButton kgButton;
    private JToggleButton lbButton;


    // TDEE and BMR Components
    static JPanel tdeePanel;
    static JPanel tdeeBMRPanel;
    static JPanel activityLevelPanel;
    static JPanel bmrTDEEValuesPanel;
    static JPanel bmrValuePanel;
    static JPanel tdeeValuePanel;
    private JLabel tdeeQuestionLabel;
    private JLabel activityLevelLabel;
    private JComboBox activityLevelBox;
    private JRadioButton tdeeYes;
    private JRadioButton tdeeNo;
    private JLabel bmrLabel;
    private JLabel tdeeLabel;




    // Default values for gender/weight/height

    String[] activityLevels = {"Sedentary", "Lightly Active", "Moderately Active", "Very Active", "Extra Active"};
    String genderSelection = "M";   
    String weightSelection = "kg";
    String heightSelection = "cm";
    String tdeeSelection = "no";




    public BmrCalcv2(String title) {

        // Main JFrame
        setTitle("BMR/TDEE Calculator");
        mainPanel = new JPanel();

        // All JPanel declarations
        menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        imgPanel = new JPanel();
        agePanel = new JPanel();
        genderPanel = new JPanel();
        heightPanel = new JPanel();
        weightPanel = new JPanel();
        weightHeightPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        combinedGAHWpanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout()); // Create a new panel used to combine
                                                            // genderPanel, agePanel, weightPanel, heightPanel below
        tdeeBMRPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        tdeePanel = new JPanel();
        activityLevelPanel = new JPanel();
        bmrTDEEValuesPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        bmrValuePanel = new JPanel();
        tdeeValuePanel = new JPanel();



        // Image panel declaration
        imgLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("filesrc//mainlogo.png"));
        imgPanel.add(imgLabel);

        // JPanel layout managers
        agePanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 5, 5));
        genderPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 5, 5));


        // Menu JComponents
        saveMenu = new JMenu("Save");
        optionMenu = new JMenu("Options");
        helpMenu = new JMenu("Help");
        menuBar.add(saveMenu);
        menuBar.add(optionMenu);
        menuBar.add(helpMenu);

        // Age JComponents
        ageLabel = new JLabel("Age:");
        yearsLabel = new JLabel("<html><i>years</i><html>");
        ageTextField = new JTextField(5);
        agePanel.add(ageLabel);
        agePanel.add(ageTextField);
        agePanel.add(yearsLabel);

        // Gender JComponents
        genderLabel = new JLabel("Gender:");
        genderMale = new JRadioButton("Male", true);
        genderFemale = new JRadioButton("Female");



        genderPanel.add(genderLabel);
        genderPanel.add(genderMale);
        genderPanel.add(genderFemale);


        ButtonGroup genderGroup = new ButtonGroup(); // groups male and female radio buttons together so that only one can be selected
        genderGroup.add(genderMale);
        genderGroup.add(genderFemale);


        genderMale.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
              String genderSelection = "M";   
            } 
        });

        genderFemale.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
              String genderSelection = "F";
            } 
        });

        // Height JComponents
        heightLabel = new JLabel("Height:");
        heightCMField = new JTextField(4);
        heightFTField = new JTextField(3);
        heightFTLabel = new JLabel("ft");
        heightINCHLabel = new JLabel("inch");
        heightINCHField = new JTextField(3);
        cmButton = new JToggleButton("cm", true);
        feetButton = new JToggleButton("feet");
        heightPanel.add(heightLabel);

        ButtonGroup heightGroup = new ButtonGroup();
        heightGroup.add(cmButton);
        heightGroup.add(feetButton);

        heightPanel.add(heightCMField);

        cmButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                  heightSelection = "cm";
                  heightPanel.remove(heightCMField);
                  heightPanel.remove(cmButton);
                  heightPanel.remove(feetButton);
                  heightPanel.remove(heightFTField);
                  heightPanel.remove(heightFTLabel);
                  heightPanel.remove(heightINCHField);
                  heightPanel.remove(heightINCHLabel);
                  heightPanel.add(heightCMField);
                  heightPanel.add(cmButton);
                  heightPanel.add(feetButton);
                  weightHeightPanel.add(heightPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                  combinedGAHWpanel.add(weightHeightPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                  mainPanel.add(combinedGAHWpanel);
                  add(mainPanel);
                  setVisible(true);
                }
            });

        feetButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                  heightSelection = "feet";
                  heightPanel.remove(heightCMField);
                  heightPanel.remove(cmButton);
                  heightPanel.remove(feetButton);
                  heightPanel.add(heightFTField);
                  heightPanel.add(heightFTLabel);
                  heightPanel.add(heightINCHField);
                  heightPanel.add(heightINCHLabel);
                  heightPanel.add(cmButton);
                  heightPanel.add(feetButton);
                  weightHeightPanel.add(heightPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                  combinedGAHWpanel.add(weightHeightPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                  mainPanel.add(combinedGAHWpanel);
                  add(mainPanel);
                  setVisible(true);
                }
            });

        heightPanel.add(cmButton);
        heightPanel.add(feetButton);


        // Weight JComponents
        weightLabel = new JLabel("Weight:");
        weightField = new JTextField(4);
        kgButton = new JToggleButton("kg", true);
        lbButton = new JToggleButton("lbs");

        weightPanel.add(weightLabel);
        weightPanel.add(weightField);
        weightPanel.add(kgButton);
        weightPanel.add(lbButton);

        ButtonGroup weightGroup = new ButtonGroup();
        weightGroup.add(kgButton);
        weightGroup.add(lbButton);


        kgButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                weightSelection = "kg"; 
            }
        });

        lbButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                weightSelection = "lb"; 
            }
        });


        // tdee JComponents
        tdeeQuestionLabel = new JLabel("Calculate TDEE Also?");
        tdeeYes = new JRadioButton("Yes");
        tdeeNo = new JRadioButton("No", true);

        ButtonGroup tdeeButton = new ButtonGroup();
        tdeeButton.add(tdeeYes);
        tdeeButton.add(tdeeNo);

        tdeePanel.add(tdeeQuestionLabel);
        tdeePanel.add(tdeeYes);
        tdeePanel.add(tdeeNo);


        // activitylevel JComponents

        activityLevelLabel = new JLabel("Activity Level: ");
        activityLevelBox = new JComboBox(activityLevels);
        activityLevelBox.setSelectedIndex(0);

        activityLevelPanel.add(activityLevelLabel);
        activityLevelPanel.add(activityLevelBox);
        activityLevelBox.setEnabled(false);

        tdeeYes.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                  tdeeSelection = "yes";
                  activityLevelBox.setEnabled(true);
                }
            });

        tdeeNo.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                  tdeeSelection = "no";
                  activityLevelBox.setEnabled(false);
                }
            });



        // tdee and BMR value components

        bmrLabel = new JLabel("BMR: ");
        tdeeLabel = new JLabel("TDEE: ");
        bmrLabel.setFont(new Font("Monotype Corsiva",1,20));
        tdeeLabel.setFont(new Font("Monotype Corsiva",1,20));


        bmrTDEEValuesPanel.add(new JButton("Calculate"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        bmrTDEEValuesPanel.add(bmrLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        bmrTDEEValuesPanel.add(tdeeLabel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);





        // Adding sub JPanels to main JPanel
        mainPanel.add(imgPanel);

        combinedGAHWpanel.add(agePanel, BorderLayout.NORTH); // Combine genderPanel and agePanel (which are both flowLayouts) into a
                                                             // single BorderLayout panel where agePanel is given the Northern spot and
                                                             // genderPanel is given the center spot in the panel
        weightHeightPanel.add(weightPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH); // Nested borderlayouts, the weightHeightPanel is another borderLayout which is nested
                                                                 // into the southern position of the combinedGAHW border layout.
        weightHeightPanel.add(heightPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        weightHeightPanel.add(tdeeBMRPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);




        combinedGAHWpanel.add(genderPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        combinedGAHWpanel.add(weightHeightPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


        mainPanel.add(combinedGAHWpanel);


        // adding to tdeeBMRPanel
        tdeeBMRPanel.add(tdeePanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        tdeeBMRPanel.add(activityLevelPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);


        tdeeBMRPanel.add(bmrTDEEValuesPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


        // Adding main JPanel and menubar to JFrame
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        add(mainPanel);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BmrCalcv2 gui = new BmrCalcv2("BMR/TDEE Calculator");

        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gui.setVisible(true);
        gui.setSize(330, 500);
        gui.setResizable(false);

    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is occurring because you're adding another field and label to the UI and the use of `BorderLayout` to layout the components/button

Comment: Suggestion, don't change the field/label.  All the information you need is available on the screen, the toggle buttons act as the "hint" to the user for the type of information they should enter, you don't need the "cm" or "inch" labels and the field should never change, cause it just doesn't care

Comment: So you're suggesting I only give the user one method to enter the required info? @MadProgrammer

Comment: No, I'm suggesting you use one field for both the feet/cm's.  The toggle buttons are already telling the user what the field expects, so you don't need additional labels.

Answer (score 1):

This is combination of changes you are making to the UI (adding/removing labels/fields) and the compound use of a `BorderLayout`.

You actually don't need to change the label/field when you toggle between "feet" and "CM", as this all the information that the user needs is already available to them (in the form of the buttons).

I'd get rid of the `heightFTField`, `heightINCHField` and make this a single field, using the `JToggleButton`'s `selected` state to determine how you should calculate the values.  I'd also get rid of the `heightFTLabel`, `heightINCHLabel` labels, they are adding little value to the UI that the toggle buttons are already doing.

Now, having done, you can get rid of the `cmButton` and `feetButton`'s `ActionListener`s, as they provide no useful operations.

In future, you may find changing component's visibility state easier.

## Based on comments, a basic example

This demonstrates the use of a single field, `ButtonGroup` to manage the selection of the `JToggleButton`s and `JToggleButton#isSelected` to control the logic path

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JToggleButton;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class JavaApplication63 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JavaApplication63();
    }

    public JavaApplication63() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JTextField height;
        private JToggleButton cmBtn;
        private JToggleButton feetBtn;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            height = new JTextField(10);
            cmBtn = new JToggleButton("CM");
            feetBtn = new JToggleButton("Ft");

            ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
            bg.add(cmBtn);
            bg.add(feetBtn);
            feetBtn.setSelected(true);

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);

            add(height, gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            add(cmBtn, gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            add(feetBtn, gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

            JButton calc = new JButton("Calculate");
            calc.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    double valueInCms = 0;
                    if (cmBtn.isSelected()) {
                        valueInCms = Double.parseDouble(height.getText());
                    } else if (feetBtn.isSelected()) {
                        String text = height.getText().replace("'", ".").replace("\"", "");
                        double feet = Double.parseDouble(text);
                        valueInCms = feet * 30.48;
                    }

                    System.out.println("valueInCms = " + valueInCms);
                }
            });
            add(calc, gbc);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80714/discussion-between-madprogrammer-and-ftahir192).

Comment: I'm hoping its okay to ask a question regarding the setVisible thing. I tried to do it to cmButton:
cmButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         heightSelection = "cm";
         heightINCHField.setVisible(false);
         heightFTField.setVisible(false);
         heightFTLabel.setVisible(false);
         heightINCHLabel.setVisible(false);
         heightCMField.setVisible(true);

but it doesn't work. When I press feet and then cm, no fields or labels pop up. Thats the only thing I changed, is there more to it?

Comment: Call `revalidate` and `repaint` on the containers which contain the components you are making in/visible

Comment: Containers as in JPanel? Can you give me an example?

Comment: You should do it after you've made all the changes. `JPanel` == containers, it's a "container" of components ;)

Comment: weightPanel.repaint();
         weightPanel.revalidate(); 

I added these 2 lines into the eventListener but still didn't work. Am I missing some code outside of the eventListener?

Comment: `revalidate` first, `repaint `second`

Comment: Still didn't seem to make a difference. Let me play about with it and see what I can do.

Comment: It could be an issue with the compound containers, you might need to revalidate the top level container (as well)

Comment: Yeah, I've revalidated them all and it seemed to fix the cm button, but feet button has problems because I didn't add them before hand to the containers like I did with cm (as cm is my default)

Comment: heightPanel.add(heightCMField);
  heightPanel.add(heightFTField);
  heightPanel.add(heightFTLabel);
  heightPanel.add(heightINCHField);
  heightPanel.add(heightINCHLabel);
So I've had to add that whereas first it was just the first line. And then I need to set the last 4 as initially setVisible(false). This will make the code alot longer than it was - is my original way not a good way to do it? Is there any way I can add and setVisible(false) in one line?

Comment: Nevermind, about the same length of code, but now I get the satisfaction of knowing I did it properly rather than some brute method. Works perfectly now, thanks!

Comment: Okay, I think I see what your problem is.  Add ALL the components you need to the UI at the start and change the visibility state of the components as needed for the initial state.  Then, as required, change them later.  The components need to be in a container before they can be shown ;)

Comment: Yeah that was what the problem was. Initially I only had cmField, I had to add feetField, inchField, inchLabel etc and then set their visibility to false. I will take your other advice tomorrow and make it so that I actually don't need to use this and just have 1 field for both types of inputs, but I wanted to do this for education purposes. Thanks :)

Comment: Just a general question, wheres a good place where I can see what methods can be used for certain objects? I.e. I didn't know I could use setVisible on a JLabel, where can I look for this information? Even this page http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html doesn't tell me that I can unless I'm missing something

Comment: If you scroll towards the bottom of the summary, you will see sections called  "Methods inherited from class ..." this shows all the methods that the class inherits.  Not brilliant, but it's a jumping off point ;)

Comment: Ah, knew I missed something. I probably should have just used Ctrl + F, but its 5am, done watching E3 and can't think anymore lol. Cheers